# Compare Post Meta Wordpress to Date

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a meta_key as listing_expiry_date and its storing date (e.g. 2017-11-30 12:25:57). I believe its storing date as string as the meta_value field in the database is longtext

Now. I would like to get post array for posts that are expiring in one day. the code that I have developed is as follows.

```
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')+1;

$args = array('posts_per_page' => $show, 

        'post_type' => $type, 'orderby' => $orderby, 'order' => $order, 'paged'  => $paged,

        'meta_query' => array (

                array (

                    'key' => 'listing_expiry_date',                                                             

                    'orderby' => 'meta_value',                       

                    'compare' => '<=',

                    'value' => $today,

                    'type'=> 'date'         
                )

              ) 

         );
```

This code works sometimes and sometimes I am getting posts that have expiry date of 3 and 5 and 7 days. I do not really know what is wrong.

Also, I would appreciate if you someone would help and show me how to display posts that have one hour remaining only.

Thanks guys.

Comment: If its longtext why are you trying to compare it as date?

Comment: How to compare it then ?? any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
$one_day_expiry = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date .' +1 day'));
$one_hour_expiry = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date .' +1 hour'));

$args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => $show, 
                'post_type' => $type, 
                'orderby' => $orderby, 
                'order' => $order, 
                'paged'  => $paged,
                'meta_query' => array (
                                        'relation' => 'AND',
                                        array (
                                                'key' => 'listing_expiry_date',                       
                                                'compare' => '<=',
                                                'value' => $one_day_expiry,
                                                'type'=> 'date'         
                                            )

                                    ) 

             );
```

The mistake you were doing was at generating next day's date. for getting posts expiring in next one hour try replacing `$one_day_expiry` variable with `$one_hour_expiry` variable in meta query.

Hope this will help you.